# Selectively blocking Django error e-mails

Tags: django

Is there a simple way to keep Django from sending error E-mails for certain views or URLs?

I noticed today, that there are some errors that happen on our login view.  And since Django includes POST data in these E-mails, it's E-mailing cleartext passwords.  This is obviously not ideal and I'd rather not have to kill the whole system to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django allows you to either specify sensitive variables to omit from the traceback on a per-view basis, or write your own filtering logic and tie that in for all email notifications.  I think that was first added in 1.4.  The docs have good examples:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#sensitive_variables

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#custom-error-reports

Answer (score 0):

Django does not provide a way to filter email on a per-view or per-URL basis.

There are two common ways to deal with this situation:

1. Fix the condition causing the error
2. Filter the email on the receiving end